# How to create a shortcode for categories in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is what I am trying to do:

```
  function second_option() {  
    $categories = get_categories('child_of=62'); 
    $output = '';
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
      $output .= '<option value="'.$category->cat_name.'">';
    }
    return $output;
  }  
  add_shortcode("option_2", "second_option");
```

But I am getting an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works for me, basically had empty categories so I had to provide the show empty cat on the query and also declare the array.

```
  function second_option() {
    $descendant= array('child_of'=>62, 'hide_empty' => 0);
    $categories = get_categories($descendant);
    $option = " ";
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
      $option .= '<option>'.$category->name.'</option>';
    }
    return $option;
  }  
  add_shortcode("option_2", "second_option");
```

Now I can use:

`[option_2]` anywhere